# http://www.beautyoftheweb.com effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gwt

how is the  transition/slide effect is done for http://www.beautyoftheweb.com ?   using jquery/javascript/css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a combination of things, including jQuery, Prototype *and* Silverlight for the intro/navigation.  If you view source at the bottom, [you'll see many included plugins](http://www.beautyoftheweb.com/).

[The main code is here though](http://www.beautyoftheweb.com/assets/scripts/globals.js?v=1.0.3965.24477) (`globals.js`), look for `InitializeWebsite()` to see where it all gets kicked off...the majority of the code is in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

to start, just opening the source and searching for ".js" , you can see that jQuery is loaded.
How much it is used, is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be jQuery made. Use a firebug you'll see how the elements are populated and modified.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems that it has done using jquery. You yourself can check this and debug code using [`firebug`](http://getfirebug.com/) , a firefox add on.