# www.beautyoftheweb.com effect with GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, uibinder

any gwt library i can use to create sliding effect like [www.beautyoftheweb.com](http://www.beautyoftheweb.com) ?

Comment: You need to refine this question - **describe** the effect you want, and point to the URL as an example.  Right now it's not clear what you want at all (e.g. I could assume that you're talking about the "text colour changes on hover" effect of the top menu ;-)).

Comment: the sliding effect when click on left menu and the view is slided in

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://www.beautyoftheweb.com effect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183161/http-www-beautyoftheweb-com-effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102956/what-effects-libraries-are-available-for-gwt-for-commercial-use) for a list of some fx libraries available for GWT. Check their project pages and evaluate which of them suites your needs best.